# Avoiding localiztion on formatting numbers written to file

Tags: c#, localization, format, numbers

I have a program that sometimes is used in locales that use commas for the decimal separator.  Its nice how C# handles all that (good for the UI), but when I export to a file, I need to always use a ".", not the locale specific number.  Currently, I do:

String.Format("{0:0.####},{1:0.####}", x, y)

Problem is that in some locales, that ends up using commas instead of periods.  Question is, is there a format code that says "always use period", or is the only solution to mess with one's locale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.####},{1:0.####}", x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying FxCop (or the Code Analysis feature of the Team variants of VS2005+).
It generates a lot of noise (false positives), but does provide a lot of good practice.

Including: always use the overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` parameter if one is available - typically you will use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for formatting output for the user, and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for storing data in files, the registry etc.